# Prevent bundling node module by dynamic import doesn't work

Tags: typescript, webpack, dynamic-import

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

import clsx from 'clsx';

import Loader from 'icons/Loader';

import { useMountEffect } from 'hooks';

import styles from './styles.scss';

interface Props {
  label: string;
  value: any;
  className?: string;
  inputProps: {
    onChange: (e: any) => void;
  };
  setValue: (name: string, value: string) => void;
}

const RichText = ({ value = '', className, inputProps, label }: Props) => {
  const ref = useRef<any>();

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  const { onChange, ...restProps } = inputProps;

  useMountEffect(() => {
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "react-quill" */ 'react-quill').then((data) => {
      ref.current = data.default;
      setLoaded(true);
    });
  });

  const modules = {
    toolbar: [['bold', 'italic', 'underline'], [{ align: [] }]],
  };

  const formats = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'];

  const ReactQuill = ref.current;

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>

      {ReactQuill && loaded ? (
        <ReactQuill
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          formats={formats}
          modules={modules}
          className={clsx(styles.root, className)}
          {...restProps}
        />
      ) : (
        <div className={styles.loading}>
          <Loader />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RichText;
```

Above you can see that I try to load dynamically package. As I understand it should not be in bundle size as it loads dynamically, but I see it in my bundle. I use webpack 5. I also use typescript

```
{
    mode: env.mode,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    stats: {
      errorDetails: true,
    },
    ...(isProduction && {
      optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendor',
              chunks: 'all',
            },
          },
        },
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            extractComments: false,
          }),
        ],
      },
    }),
    module: {
      rules: [rules.ts(), rules.scss(), rules.css()],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
      path: paths.public,
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.environment.tap('removePublicFolder', () => {
            execSync('rm -rf public');
          });
        },
      },
      new CompressionPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: isDevServer ? 'main.css' : '[name].[hash].css',
        ignoreOrder: true,
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),
      }),
      new WebpackManifestPlugin({
        publicPath: '',
      }),
      {
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.done.tap('done', () => {
            execSync('npm run view-file');
            execSync('ls');
          });
        },
      },
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: paths.static, to: paths.public }],
      }),
    ],
  };
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "public"]
}
```

I've also attached typescript and webpack configurations

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has nothing to do with dynamic imports

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

in .babelrc

```
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
```

then in webpack config:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
```

[check documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

Comment: have you tried it ?) it doesn't work, I've shown that I have chunks spliting , problem with node modules, when I lazy loading files (components), which in my project , it works properly

Comment: Since webpack 5, passing an entry name to {cacheGroup}.test and using a name of an existing chunk for {cacheGroup}.name is no longer allowed.